# Perl: how to share the import of a large list of modules between many independent scripts?

Tags: perl, module

I have many standalone scripts. The only thing they share, is that they use() a large set of CPAN modules (that each export several functions). I would like to centralize this list of modules. I found several methods. Which one is the best?

1. I could create SharedModules.pm that imports everything and then manually exports everything to main:: using Exporter.
2. I could create SharedModules.pm that starts with "package main;" so it will import directly into main::. It seems to work. Is it bad practice and why?
3. I could require() a sharedmodules.pl that seems to import everything into main:: as well. I don't like this method as require() doesn't work that well under mod_perl.

Number two looks best to me, however I wonder why for example Modern::Perl doesn't work that way.

Edit: I figured this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437785/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-file-that-in-turn-uses-multiple-others-in-perl).

Comment: Don't sweat it; that's why [dupes aren't all that bad.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: Also see: [Toolkit](http://p3rl.org/Toolkit)

Comment: I just recently found [ToolSet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ToolSet) -- it is possible to arrange modules for import easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with all three of your proposed solutions is that the module may be `use`d from another module, in which case the symbols should be exported into the `use`ing module's package, not into `main`.

bvr's solution of using `caller` to import things directly into that package is a major step in the right direction, but prevents the 'real' package from using `use ShareableModules qw( foo bar baz);` to selectively import only what it actually needs.

Unfortunately, preserving the ability to import selectively will require you to import all relevant symbols from the underlying modules and then re-export them from ShareableModules.  You can't just delegate the import to each underlying module's `import` method (as `Modern::Perl` does) because `import` dies if it's asked for a symbol that isn't exported by that module.  If that's not an issue, though, then `Modern::Perl`'s way of doing it is probably the cleanest and simplest option.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe more flexible than putting everything into `main` namespace would be to import into caller's namespace. Something like this:

```
package SharedModules;

sub import {

    my $pkg = (caller())[0];   # name of calling package
    eval <<"EOD";

package $pkg;                  # select target package

# list of packages to import
use List::Util;
use List::MoreUtils;

EOD
    # import function continues here
    die $@ if $@;             # check for errors, print them, and exit
}

1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) is the most natural way to do this. Under mod_perl you may need to modify `@INC` during server startup.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want [Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Toolkit).

Answer (score 1):

File import.pl:

```
require blah;  blah->import;
require blubb; blubb->import;
```

Skripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
do 'import.pl'
...
```

Patrick