# How to include a file that contains all the required Perl module names?

Tags: perl, perl-module

The perl scripts contain all the module names in the beginning of the script.

Ex:

```
use strict;
use XML::Parser;
use XML::Simple;
use DBI;
use DBD::DB2::Constants;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use Storable qw(dclone);
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
```

How to keep all the module names in another file and include the file in main perl script ?

Thanks.

Comment: Previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437785/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-file-that-in-turn-uses-multiple-others-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919625/perl-how-to-share-the-import-of-a-large-list-of-modules-between-many-independen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412799/perl-how-to-make-use-mydefaults-with-modern-perl-utf8-defaults

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own module. But, if if you make package in this module those `strftime` etc will be imported into another namespace. You can do litle hack to do this smiple:

MyModules.pm:

```
use strict;
use XML::Parser;
use XML::Simple;
use DBI;
use DBD::DB2::Constants;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use Storable qw(dclone);
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
```

Note there was no `package` keyword in this .pm. Your script:

```
use MyModules;
```

Place this .pm into same dir with script or add modules search path at runtime:

```
use lib '/my_modules_dir/';
use MyModules;
```

Use of **do** and **require** commands is not recommended, since they do not check syntax on script start. Sure you can place them into BEGIN block but i think its tricky way and generally `BEGIN{ require ..}` is the same as `use`

UPD: **ikegami** noted problem its not working when you use this from many modules. Regardless question starter's information (he want to use this from main script), ill add info how to use this from many modules, so my friend can feel better. Add to end of MyModules.pm:

```
delete $INC{'MyModules.pm'};
1;
```

Comment: Actually `use` when file doesnot contain package ends with `do` in `BEGIN` anyway. Difference that `use` will do the checks for you. And, as in case with choroba's answer you  will edit comment/catch the bugs with such simple thing like `do` command.

Comment: @ikegami yes, **use** will result **require** which itself will call **do** after checking that module isnot loaded already. And he wants to include from main script.

Comment: @ikegami everything for you, my best stackoverflow friend.

Comment: .@ PSIAlt: Thanks a lot. Why to use the statement. delete $INC{'MyModules.pm'};

Comment: @Sourcecode generally cus its a hack. But ironically Perl is 1/4 made of hacks xD

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
BEGIN { do 'filename.pl' or die $@ }
```

See [do](http://p3rl.org/do). Be sure to include `1;` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: It won't turn on strict, but it'll handle the exporter.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at the [Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Toolkit) module.